# Add text to text in file with bash

Tags: sed

I'm not a bash expert so that is why I'm asking for help to manipulate strings in file. I know about `sed` but I'm having hard time trying.

Basically I have a file with the following content:

```
docs: lala

docs: this is the description

That is the footer
```

I need to add to the **first line only** `docs: lala` the following text: `($SCOPE)` which should look like this in the end:

```
docs(some_scope_name): lala

docs: this is the description

That is the footer
```

What I have is this:

```
sed -i $FILE -e "s/docs:/docs:($SCOPE_NAME)/"
```

This works just fine, BUT is **replacing also the second docs**. I only need the first match!

Also not only docs should match, but also other types, those are:

> `build|chore|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|revert|style|test`

For example, it could also be:

```
feat(some_scope_name): lala

feat: this is the description

That is the footer
```

How should I improve my sed to achieve that?

**EDIT**

The suggested answer by @anubhava

> sed -E "0,/^[[:blank:]]*(build|chore|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|revert|style|test):/ s//\1(lala):/" $FILE

works fine but it's still replacing the sencond match:

```
docs(lala): lala

docs(lala): this is the description

That is the footer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-sed` command:

```sh
sed -i -E "1s/^[[:blank:]]*(build|chore|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|revert|style|test):/\1($SCOPE_NAME):/" file
```

Comment: thank you very much. what about other possible types other than docs as mentioned in my question? how do I include the regex in there?

Comment: Other problem is, it adds twice if the scope is already present. For example: `docs:(lala)(scope) lala`

Comment: unfortunatelly it's adding now to the second line. I'm gonna update my question for a better understanding

Comment: Try my updated answer now

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ scope=some_scope_name
$ sed "1s/\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1($scope)\2/" input_file
docs(some_scope_name): lala

docs: this is the description

That is the footer
```